# i'm trying to change the value in one dictionary by comparing the key from another dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, functional-programming

```
var clariQuestion: [String: String] = ["0": "What are my last 10 transactions",
                                    "1": "What are my spending transactions",
                                    "2": "What are my largest trasactions",
                                    "3": "What are my pending tracnstions"]

var explanationActionParameters: [String: Any] = ["clariQuestion": 2]
```

So i need to match the value of explanationActionParameters with the key of clariQuestion, and then when the keys match replace the number 2 in explanationActionParameters with "what are my largest transactions". What's causing me difficulty is that the value in explanationActionParameter is of type 2 and the key in clariQuestion is of type String. Not to sure how to go about this.

Comment: "What's causing me difficulty is that the value in explanationActionParameter is of type 2 and the key in clariQuestion is of type String" Well, why did you do that? It's your code; configure it so that the types match as needed.

Comment: Cool! If you have a solution, please provide it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can either convert your int to string, using `String(2)` or convert your string to int, like `Int("2")`
My answer to you would be to transform your clariQuestion dictionary into an array, because the keys are integers, and an array can be seen as a dictionary where the keys are integers. So, you could do

```
var clariQuestion: [String] = ["What are my last 10 transactions",
                                "What are my spending transactions",
                                "What are my largest trasactions",
                                "What are my pending tracnstions"]
var explanationActionParameters: [String: Any] = ["clariQuestion": 2]

let questionIndex = explanationActionParameters["clariQuestion"]
let question = clariQuestion[questionIndex]
```

If you insist on maintaining this dictionary structure, you can `flatmap` your dictionaries and transform all keys from string to int, like this

```
clariQuestion.flatMap { (key, value) in [Int(key) : value] }
```

or transform all your values to a string, like this

```
explanationActionParameters.flatMap { (key, value) in [key : String(value)] }
```

Either way, now you should be able to access elements across those dictionaries. I'm going to create a function demonstrating how

```
func replace(_ clariQuestion: [String : String], _ explanationActionParameters: [String: Any]) -> [String: String] {
    // The dictionary that will be returned containing the mapping from clariQuestion to explanationActionParameters
    var ret = [String : String]()
    let mappedClariQuestion = clariQuestion.flatMap { (key, value) in [Int(key) : value] }
    for (key, value) in clariQuestion {
        ret[key] = mappedClariQuestion[value]
    }

    return ret
}
```

Then, just `explanationActionParameters = replace(clariQuestion, explanationActionParameters)`